# Webform template suggestion doesn't work

Tags: 7, webforms, theming

Is there a way to suggest a template in [webform 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)?

I have tried this:

```
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'webform__form__mywebform';
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81809/using-theme-hook-suggestions-for-webform-confirmation-page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply the latest patch from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1891220
2. In your theme's template.php, in `YOURTHEME_preprocess_webform_form()`, add:

   `$path_parts = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());`

   `$path = implode('__', str_replace(array('-', ' ', '+', '.'), '_', $path_parts));`

   `$hook = $vars['theme_hook_original'];`

   `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "{$hook}__{$path}";`

Answer (score 0):

To override the template of webform you just need to name it like :

```
webform-form-[nid].tpl.php
```

No need to write the code for this.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use name not id. Because devel/stagging/production server. I would like to have naming convention.

Comment: Webform don't have any machine name? How you will differentiate from other webforms?

Comment: I would like to have it webform-form-[my-own-name].tpl.php

Comment: How it will be applied to the specific webform?

Comment: I dont understand you

Comment: Path alias is one possibility that comes to mind. Language, title, whether the current user is logged in, are all available variables that could be used in selecting a template.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this part in webform_theme() function:

```
'webform_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/webform-form',
      'pattern' => 'webform_form_[0-9]+',
    ),
```

It will ignore any suggestions if they do not match the pattern. So looks like only webform-form-[nid].tpl.php are working...

What I did (I needed only one special template for some specific webforms), I made a custom numeric suggestion with leading zero (just to be sure it's not NID).

In hook_preprocess_webform_form:

```
if ($my_custom_conditions) {
 $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'webform_form_01';
}
```

Drupal does not ignore webform-from-01.tpl.php since it matches the pattern and it won't conflict with other webforms, because of leading zero.

Hope it saves anyone's time :)