# Create tpl file for webform

Tags: theming, webforms

I have created a form using webform module. Is there any way to create tpl file for this form?

webform-form-node_id.tpl.php is working fine. Here my problem is node_id will deffer on dev,qa and production etc server.

Please suggest so that a single tpl file can used for all instance.

Comment: If using path alias for template suggestion is an option for you - [check this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/202780/49935)

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'node--webform.tpl.php' template for all webform nodes.